# The correct usage of to and in when asking if this is a person's first time in a city

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage, expressions, conversation

I'm not sure how to explain this to my student. He is asking which of the following sentences are correct:

Is this your first time TO Tokyo?

or

Is this your first time IN Tokyo?

I'm thinking the 2nd sentence is correct but I'm not sure how to explain it. Any insights would be great! THank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you are IN Tokyo, you would say, "Is this your first time in Tokyo?" and if the person was going to Tokyo, "is this your first time going to Tokyo". I don't think the first sentance really makes sense. In looking it up to find a reference to back up my answer, I found that there are no real rules about this. As a native English speaker, to Tokyo sounds incorrect to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could say: Is this your first time *in* Tokyo?

But also: Is this your first trip *to* Tokyo?

Comment: This answer merely repeats parts of the previous answer.

Comment: @TrevorD, The second half is new...